# How to join two tables but use each row only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One represents invoices that are still open (table `#OPEN`) and the other one represents available money (table `#overpay`). Both have a column `USERID` by which they can be joined:

```
CREATE TABLE #OVERPAY(OID INT, USERID CHAR(1), Rest INT)
CREATE TABLE #OPEN(IID INT, USERID CHAR(1), Amt INT, OpenROW INT)
```

The table #OPEN has a column `OpenRow` by which the open amounts are ordered (per user). I want to map entries from the table `#OVERPAY` to entries in the table `#OPEN` in the following way:

- An entry gets mapped when #OVERPAY.Rest >= #OPEN.AMT
- Smaller values in #OPEN.OpenRow get mapped first
- Each entry in #OVERPAY can only be used once
- Each entry in #OPEN can only be used once

The last two points in that list are what gives me a headache.

This is some mocked data:

```
OID    USERID   REST
--------------------
1      'A'      10 
2      'A'      15 
3      'F'      5
4      'H'      20 
5      'H'      5

INSERT INTO #OVERPAY(OID, USERID, Rest)
VALUES (1, 'A', 10), (2, 'A', 15), (3, 'F', 5),
       (4, 'H', 20), (5, 'H', 5)

OID    USERID   Amt   OpenRow
-----------------------------
1      'A'      10    1 
2      'A'      10    2
3      'A'      15    3 
4      'F'      5     1
5      'H'      15    1 
6      'H'      10    2
7      'P'      33    1

INSERT INTO #OPEN(IID, USERID, Amt, OpenROW)
VALUES (1, 'A', 10, 1), (2, 'A', 10, 2),
       (3, 'A', 15, 3), (4, 'F', 5, 1),
       (5, 'H', 15, 1), (6, 'H', 10, 2),
       (7, 'P', 33, 1)
```

The desired result would be:

```
OID    IID
----------
1      1
2      2
3      4
4      5
```

I know how I could do it with a `CURSOR`:

```
CREATE TABLE #map (OID INT, IID INT)
CREATE TABLE #usedIID(IID INT)

DECLARE @OID INT, @USERID CHAR(1), @Rest INT

DECLARE ov_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT OID, USERID, REST
    FROM #OVERPAY

OPEN ov_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ov_cursor INTO @OID, @USERID, @REST

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @IID INT

    INSERT INTO #map (OID, IID)
    OUTPUT inserted.IID INTO #usedIID (IID)
        SELECT TOP 1 @OID, o.IID
        FROM #OPEN o
        LEFT JOIN #usedIID u ON u.IID = o.IID
        WHERE o.USERID = @USERID AND o.Amt <= @REST AND u.IID IS NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM ov_cursor INTO @OID, @USERID, @REST
END

CLOSE ov_cursor
DEALLOCATE ov_cursor
```

But since this is horrible in terms of performance (I'm working with a huge set of data) I'm searching for an option to do it without any looping

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try dense_rank

```
SELECT OID, IID
FROM (
    SELECT op.OID, n.IID, OpenRow
      , dense_rank() over(partition by iid order by oid) rnkIid
      , dense_rank() over(partition by oid order by OpenRow) rnkOid
    FROM #OVERPAY op
    JOIN #OPEN n ON op.USERID = n.USERID AND op.Rest >= n.AMT
) t
WHERE rnkIid = rnkOid
ORDER BY OID, IID
```

Comment: YES! That seems to be exactly, what I'm searching for. I'll try it out in my real world scenario and come back after that. Thank you!

Comment: And nice question.